# What is an example of a benign or beneficial de novo copy number variation?

Tags: genetics, mutations

Duplication events in particular. In any species. Have enough genomes been sequenced and studied to identify any? It is rather easy to find studies which identify them with diseases but have they ever looked for benign or beneficial instances?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. This will also allow you to clarify and focus your question — as written it sounds like you haven't read this [relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_number_variation). Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: I've provided an answer, but I'm not sure whether it actually addresses the question, given "*de novo*" in the title. I assume you're looking for examples of nonpathogenic CNV mosaicism in somatic tissues? Clarifying edits would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Copy number of the human salivary amylase gene (*AMY1*) varies across populations and is positively correlated with the starch content of traditional diets.<sup>**1,2**</sup> Amylase gene copy number expansions are common in the evolutionary histories of several mammals.<sup>**3**</sup>

---

**References**

1. Perry GH, Dominy NJ, Claw KG, Lee AS, Fiegler H, Redon R, Werner J, Villanea FA, Mountain JL, Misra R, Carter NP, Lee C, Stone AC. Diet and the evolution of human amylase gene copy number variation. *Nat Genet*. 2007 Oct;39(10):1256-60.
2. Carpenter D, Mitchell LM, Armour JA. Copy number variation of human AMY1 is a minor contributor to variation in salivary amylase expression and activity. *Hum Genomics*. 2017 Feb 20;11(1):2.
3. Pajic P, Pavlidis P, Dean K, Neznanova L, Romano RA, Garneau D, Daugherity E, Globig A, Ruhl S, Gokcumen O. Independent amylase gene copy number bursts correlate with dietary preferences in mammals. *Elife*. 2019 May 14;8:e44628.